# Take urls from a json object

Tags: r

I use `jsonlite` to read a json file

Without using the specific structuring of the json is there any code which could save into a new dataframe all url which contain `"www.example.com"`

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Ask a reproducible example refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example